# How to configure UITableViewCell with UICollectionView asynchronously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Please, can someone help me with such question? In my UITableViewCell I have a UICollectionView I'm using [NHBalancedFlowLayout](https://github.com/njdehoog/NHBalancedFlowLayout) layout so I would like to know is there a way to configure the content of this cell asynchronously?

**Q.** Why do I need this?

**A.** Sometimes my tableView scroll lags when such cell is configuring.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/ShuW780K) is my cell class

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to break the procedure up into a series of steps? Push step 1 onto the main queue. When step 1 completes it pushes step 2 onto the main queue. Repeat until done.

Comment: @RobertVaessen what do you mean under "procedure"?

Comment: The  things that you are doing to create and/or update the cell which contains the collection view.

Comment: BTW: Using the main queue assumes that each of the steps requires the manipulation of UI objects; else another queue (i.e thread) could be used. My idea (not 100% positive) is that breaking the work up into a sequence of steps that are put on the main queue will allow the main run loop to still respond to the user.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you should everything UI related on the main thread. You can do the logic/calculation on different thread and update ui on the main queue. If I have any problems with lags/frame drops. I use AsyncDisplayKit (framework developed by Facebook) in more complicated UIs.

Comment: I know about the AsyncDisplayKit framework but I'm not sure that I want to rewrite my project, I'll try to solve the problem with UIKit. I'll up your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode Instruments to reveal places in your code with performance and memory issues. May be images you are trying to display are too big, displaying high resolution pics is always a bottleneck. May be NHBalancedFlowLayout gives lag... Just run with profiling.